# How can I pass json list to a model class

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi im creating this model class Users and it look like this

```
class User {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  Address? address;
  String? phone;
  String? website;
  Company? company;

  User(
      {this.id,
        this.name,
        this.username,
        this.email,
        this.address,
        this.phone,
        this.website,
        this.company});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    address =
    json['address'] != null ? new Address.fromJson(json['address']) : null;
    phone = json['phone'];
    website = json['website'];
    company =
    json['company'] != null ? new Company.fromJson(json['company']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['username'] = this.username;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    if (this.address != null) {
      data['address'] = this.address!.toJson();
    }
    data['phone'] = this.phone;
    data['website'] = this.website;
    if (this.company != null) {
      data['company'] = this.company!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Address {
  String? street;
  String? suite;
  String? city;
  String? zipcode;
  Geo? geo;

  Address({this.street, this.suite, this.city, this.zipcode, this.geo});

  Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    street = json['street'];
    suite = json['suite'];
    city = json['city'];
    zipcode = json['zipcode'];
    geo = json['geo'] != null ? new Geo.fromJson(json['geo']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['street'] = this.street;
    data['suite'] = this.suite;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['zipcode'] = this.zipcode;
    if (this.geo != null) {
      data['geo'] = this.geo!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Geo {
  String? lat;
  String? lng;

  Geo({this.lat, this.lng});

  Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    lat = json['lat'];
    lng = json['lng'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['lat'] = this.lat;
    data['lng'] = this.lng;
    return data;
  }
}

class Company {
  String? name;
  String? catchPhrase;
  String? bs;

  Company({this.name, this.catchPhrase, this.bs});

  Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    catchPhrase = json['catchPhrase'];
    bs = json['bs'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['catchPhrase'] = this.catchPhrase;
    data['bs'] = this.bs;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and this is the json response im getting from API

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  }
]
```

this is the controller im using to pass the json to model class

```
class user_controller extends GetxController {
  final user_repo repo;

  user_controller({required this.repo});
  List<dynamic> userList = [];
  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    Response response = await repo.getUserData();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      userList.add(User.fromJson(response.body));
    } else {}
  }
}
```

but I pass the response like this it generates an error

List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

I change the class like this `User.fromJson(List<dynamic> json)`  like that way I can pass the data like this `id =json[0]["id"]`

but it only pass the id of first element of the list

How Can I pass all the data? this list has 5 map object I want to display all this data on a listview using this model

Answer (score 2):

Your api response is a list so you need to change your `controller` to this:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   userList = (response.body as List).map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
} else {}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) it will generate a model from json and give you the functions to use to turn a json to model or list or the inverse